# Disappearing questions

Tags: support

A few days ago I asked a question about the inadequate performance of the newfangled rendering of the math formula display.  It has disappeared.  What happened to it?

Comment: You asked this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356018/mathnl-code-does-not-view-well This does not appear to be about the software that powers the SE platform and hence was closed as off-topic and subsequently deleted

Comment: It didn't "disappear", it was deleted. Full details can be found in the faq.

Comment: Given the points in the answer and its comments, can you edit your deleted question so it's clearer. You can then flag it for a moderator to undelete it.

Answer (score 6):

It wasn't very clear what it was about. I feel like we're missing a bunch of context, even for the MSE audience. Googling mathnl wasn't helpful

For reference

> Images with that newfangled NL code thing are weird. Verticle alignment makes for difficult to impossible reading. Math expressions longer than one line get truncated. MathNL rendition does not work. TeX renditions are as described above. In addition now, significant portions of a question are faded and perhaps smaller. Faded print makesfor harder reading and was orginally used for unimportant stuff. In summary that stack update is an updegrade, a popular occurence in these baazar days. So what does it take to get that upgrade to work right?

is the text of the question.

> Images with that newfangled NL code thing are weird.

Never heard of math NL, and "NL code thing" is imprecise.

A better way might be to give an example of what's wrong, and both the rendered and unrendered markdown or mathjax in use

> Verticle alignment makes for difficult to impossible reading.

Needs screenshot

> Math expressions longer than one line get truncated. MathNL rendition does not work. TeX renditions are as described above. In addition now, significant portions of a question are faded and perhaps smaller. Faded print makesfor harder reading and was orginally used for unimportant stuff.

Needs context and examples

> In summary that stack update is an updegrade, a popular occurence in these baazar days. So what does it take to get that upgrade to work right?

Can't even parse this.

So, fundamentally - I don't think what the issue is is clear, and there's no real obvious way for us to clarify it. We don't even know where to start.

So it might be worth starting with a little spellcheck, and considering apparently we don't know what you know.

Start with a post. Show us what you are doing, what you get, and how that's different from your expectations.

Comment: "baazar" probably meant "bizarre" (though bazaar is a thing, it doesn't fit here). Not sure what the sentence as a whole means though.

Comment: I think math NL is probably a typo for [MathML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML)

Comment: @Robert we can only guess. When we have to guess such things, it usually means the post is beyond repair anyway. (So even if not off topic, should be deleted)

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard Well yes, even if I replace NL by ML when I read it, it doesn't help much.

Comment: does SE use MathML anywhere?

Comment: It uses [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on various sites which is based on MathML.

Comment: Were there recent changes to that?

Comment: I have enough rep to see the deleted question. I don't see any comments though. Did no one think of asking the OP to clarify what they meant, or fix the typos, or at least guide them to the most relevant site? No comments asking for clarification or explaining why the question was off-topic? As a newcomer to Meta I can certainly imagine being shocked to no longer finding a post of mine which was posted only two days earlier.

Comment: I have voted to reopen because it is not a duplicate of the older question. The OP is not asking why their post was deleted, they are asking what happened to it. That's a significant difference. How could they know it was deleted? Did they receive a notification warning them of the incidence?

Comment: @Mari it disappeared because it was deleted, the faq explains why. I stand behind the closure. As for comments, someone usually leave the canned "Welcome to meta, ..." for some reason it was left out on this one, but the close banner is clear enough: "This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center." The OP is **not** new, they have account here for over two years. (Active account, including several posts)

Comment: SE runs MathJax 2.7.5 and that version is released in 2018: https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-v2-7-5-now-available/  I don't expect that has changed recently.